# How can I read data sent from form using FormData with ajax and store it to local folder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, multipartform-data

This is my ajax code on client side:

```
$('#btn_file').on('change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();            
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('photo', $('#btn_file')[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/media/images",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
 });
```

And this is my server side:

```
app.post('/media/images', function (req, res) {
   //What do I have to do to get an image and save it? And how do I rename the file?

});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="send_image" ction=”/media/images” method=”post” enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
     <input type="file" name="photo" id="btn_file"/>
</form>
```

I've found a few examples but none of them works. I really dont know where the problem is.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Node JS to manage file uploads you can use Formidable: https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable#readme

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
app.post('/media/images', function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'image/jpeg'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
});
```

Then to store the file you can use "fs" api.

Comment: excellent! it works like a charm! i found an example with formidable but i couldnt get it to work! thank you! Could I get some more help with fs?